# Effect on updated research on questions

Tags: support

For example, as regards [Has increased computer use led to increased myopia?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1964/has-increased-computer-use-led-to-increased-myopia), this was published 2 months later: http://edition.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/06/01/myopia.causes/. How might this affect the articles at https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/search?q=myopia?

Answer (score 1):

Updated research might affect the answers. You can:

- Post a new answer to an existing question, if new research provides a new answer
- Post a comment underneath a existing answer, if new research confirms or denies an existing answer

Newer research isn't necessarily better (or more informative, or more peer-reviewed) than older research (so it's not necessarily worth posting); but it might be.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, new evidence won't affect the old answers -- the default action should be doing nothing.

Furthermore, new evidence does not necessarily mean *better* evidence. This is the reason why meta-studies are favored: they study *all the available studies* based on their quality -- as such they are likely to be the "final word" on a matter, when they show a definitive conclusion.

In such cases, I can tell you that almost certainly only a new, better meta-study will be needed to change an answer. We don't want to add answers or ping users about lower quality material.